# How to Set input range value dynamically by using angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

How to set the input range value dynamically with angular 2.I am able to get the value when I set the value,but I need to set dynamic value first to input range. 
here i tried some code

```
 <input type="range"  id="range" min="0" max="100" value="100"   
 (input)="transperancy(Transvalue.value)" #Transvalue>
```

here I set value 100 default.that value i need to set dynamic from component.

```
 transperancy(value:any){
        console.log(value);
        }
```

Comment: What does "dynamic" mean in the context of this question?

Comment: I have the value of that range value in my component for ex :67, now i have to set that 67 value to input range value.

Comment: Just bind a ngModel with element and change its value whenever required ?

Comment: simply use one-way or two-way data binding value for your attibute

Comment: thanks for all your comments ,two way data binding is working.value="{{inputValue}}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <input type="range"  id="range" min="0" max="{{inputRange(range)}}"
  value="50"   min="{{inputRange(range)}}"
 (input)="transperancy(Transvalue.value)" #Transvalue> 

 min_input:number;
 max_input:number;
 min_length:number;
 max_length:number;

 inputRange(type) {
 console.log(type);
 let inputType;
 switch (type) {
 case 'text':
   inputType = 'text';
   break;
 case 'numeric':
   inputType = 'number';
   this.min_length=5;
   this.max_length=20;
   break;

 case 'number':
   inputType = 'number';
   this.min_input=0;
   this.max_input=10;
  break;
 case 'range':
   inputType = 'range';
   this.min_input=0;
   this.max_input=10;
  break;
 default:
}
return inputType;
}
}
```

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/BXpqr60PRO0GXOzsljhq?p=preview)